# Reset child directive form from parent directive

Tags: angularjs

Reset child directive form from parent directive

```
<parent>
    <child></child>
<parent>
```

In above example there should be a "child" directive which have some text fields I  want to reset that fields value on some event which should be trigger from parent directive . 
Note we are not using controller.

Comment: You're not using a controller anywhere?

Comment: Yes we are only working on directive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use broadcasting to trigger reset.
Also from parent  to child you cannot access scope data whearas from child to parent you can. Hope this helps!!

Comment: Hello, would be better for completeness of your answer if you could add some example code of your suggestion, also, will help other users with the same problem. Please refer to [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).